# Finding the continuous windows of length k grouped by ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, window-functions

Given this

| ID | rownum | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | false |
| 100 | 2 | false |
| 100 | 3 | true |
| 100 | 4 | **false** |
| 100 | 5 | **false** |
| 100 | 6 | **false** |
| 100 | 7 | true |
| 100 | 8 | false |
| 100 | 9 | false |
| 101 | 1 | **false** |
| 101 | 2 | **false** |
| 101 | 3 | **false** |
| 101 | 4 | true |
| 101 | 5 | **false** |
| 101 | 6 | **false** |
| 101 | 7 | **false** |

I need this

| ID | Counts |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |

Basically finding the count of continuous 'false' windows of length 3 (can be any length) by grouping by ID. I tried simple count() function grouping by ID, it did not work, it just returned the total count by groups.

I am using PostgreSQL latest version (14.1). Also, it is a fairly large database (10M+ rows)

Comment: @Renat No, the data is not sorted by value but by ID.

Comment: I understand your point. There is 1 more column for index, like a rownumber, so 1st False is different from 2nd False as row number would be different and ID+rownumber is primary key.

Comment: What if there are 4 or more continuous 'false'? Does this count as 1?

Comment: If there are 4, that will count as 1 but if there are 6, it will count as 2. Similarly, for 7,8 it will be 2 counts but for 9, it will be 3 counts. Basically, divide by 3 and then floor operation.

Answer (score 0):

Using `LAG` and `SUM OVER` it's possible to calculate a rank per ID for continues values.

Once there's a ranking, it's simple to aggregate on it.

> ```
> SELECT ID, SUM(FLOOR(RankTotal/3)) AS Counts
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT ID, Rnk, COUNT(*) AS RankTotal
>     FROM
>     (
>         SELECT *
>         , SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY rownum) AS Rnk
>         FROM
>         (
>             SELECT ID, rownum, Value
>             , CASE 
>               WHEN Value = LAG(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY rownum) 
>               THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flag
>             FROM your_table
>         ) q1
>         WHERE Value = false
>     ) q2
>     GROUP BY ID, Rnk
>     HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
> ) q3
> GROUP BY ID
> ORDER BY ID;
> ```

| id | counts |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 102 | 4 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b56a182ce7378c3f273014769550e702)*

Comment: This will give a count of 1 instead of 2 for the window of size 6. That can be changed so no problem however, the query is too slow as the database is very large. Any way to optimize it further?

Comment: Groups of 3.  need to rethink this.

Comment: @PruthiviRaj See updated solution.  Made it a tiny bit faster.  But I don't personally see a faster way atm. I assume there's a non-unique index on ID?  Maybe someone knows a faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified @LukStorms' solution to count groups by chunks of length 3.

```
SELECT ID, sum(cnt) AS Counts
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, Rnk, (COUNT(*) - 3) / 3 + 1 AS Cnt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        , SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY rownum) AS Rnk
        FROM
        (
            SELECT ID, rownum, Value
            , CASE 
              WHEN Value = LAG(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY rownum) 
              THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flag
            FROM your_table
        ) q1
        WHERE Value = false
    ) q2
    GROUP BY ID, Rnk
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
) q3
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8bb0abfb735f9820f7da1de5c0d3bcc4)